# Configuration Symfony3 with netbeans

Tags: netbeans, symfony

I would like to know if netbeans support Symfony 3.1.0?
If any one have an idea which version of netbeans should'i use.
Thanks

Comment: I realize that this might not be helpful a bit, but Netbeans is bad choice to begin with... seriously bad...

Comment: @JovanPerovic - You are correct.  Your comment is completely unhelpful as well as being totally inaccurate.

Comment: Sorry, I understand that my comment was highly biased. It is just that my experience with NetBeans and PHP was very unpleasant and therefor very short...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the OS you use, for Windows, NetBeans is a good choice. Paragraph git installed using the console and composer to create New Projects Symfony.

Should also have installed WAMP or XAMPP

from the console git:

```
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition my_project_name
```

In netbeans:

- Activate PHP in Netbeans (https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/configure-php-environment-windows.html)
- Then in Netbeans open project > path_project_folder_www
- Right click on the project > properties, and change the project path: 
  [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6UEX.png)